# Which letters of celebrētur are trilled in this Bervoets recording

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation

Which letters of *celebrētur* are trilled in this recording? https://www.stilus.nl/ce-geluid/PlinMinEp-VI-16.htm? Bervoets doesn't just trills both R's but the letters near the two R's too! I've noticed the same thing in a non Bervoets recording in which the word has two R's that aren't next to each other: when Ben Johnson of LatinTutorial when he says the word Februarius for the last time! youtube.com/watch?v=N6dU98dXhkA&t=138s

Comment: (Obligatory not my downvote, but...) I'm not sure what you're asking here. Can you reword your question to clarify what you mean?

Comment: In particular, what does "the pronunciation that the tongue does" mean? The tongue is involved in most pronunciation.

Comment: The vibrations that the tongue does!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. When you say "On what letter", well, it starts on the first letter of the word, so it starts on C. Are you asking about the pronunciation of C? Or about the syllable?

Comment: The word starts on the letter C but the vibrations that the tongue doesn't start on the letter C!

Comment: With all respect, you've asked basically this same question several times both here and on Linguistics, and the answer we can give is the same as always: the "tongue vibrations" are the alveolar trill /r/, represented by the letter R in Latin. If that's not the answer you're looking for (which it seemingly isn't because you're asking again), you need to clarify _why_ that doesn't answer your question, and what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Ana Maria: I edited your post as to what I think you're asking. Please let us know if that's not quite what you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, That's what I'm asking! Bervoets doesn't just trills both R's but the letters near the two R's! too! I've noticed the same thing in a non Bervoets recording in which the word has two R's that aren't next to each other: when Ben Johnson of LatinTutorial when he says the word Februarius for the last time! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6dU98dXhkA&t=138s

Comment: Can you please edit the details of your last comment into the question itself? As it stands, the question gives a very different impression of what you want than your comments below. Everyone should be able to understand your question without reading comments.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I understand what you're asking now. When I listened to it, to me it sounds like he trills *both* R's in celebrētur, and the latter one elides into the following word (*ā*).

Hope this helps.